# Coordinate hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading a text about linear algebra and I see experssion  " Coordinate hyperplane $\{x_i=0\}$ in $\mathbb R^n$  " in the book. But the book didn't has  some definition for it . Then I do search on the web and I did not find something about it. what is it? Do anybody know it?

Comment: This is the $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ consisting of all points $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ with $x_i=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hyperplane is an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace.  A subspace is a subset of a linear/ affine space that is also a linear/ affine space.  In this case, they mean the linear subspace where the extent of the hyperplane along the $i$th standard basis vector is $0$.

For instance, the hyperplane $x_2=0$ is the set of vectors $\{(x_1, \cdots, v_n) \in \Bbb R^n \mid x_2 = 0\}$ along with the usual operations of scalar multiplication and vector addition.

In $\Bbb R^3$, we typically denote $x_1, x_2, x_3$ as $x,y,z$.  So one of the $3$ hyperplanes with this description is $x_2=y=0$ -- which is just the $x$-$z$ plane.

Comment: What's meaning of "the Coordinate hyperplane $\{v_i=0\}$ " where $V\in \mathbb R^n$ , $v_i:=<V,e_i>$ and $e_i$ is a member from an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: $v_i$ is just the $i$th component of $V$.  So if I understand you correctly, this is the same subspace.  That is, let $V$ be an arbitrary vector in $\Bbb R^3$ with $\langle V, e_i\rangle =0$.  The set of all such $V$ is just the hyperplane with no extent along the direction given by $e_i$.

Comment: @Bye-World, I attend you that In $R^n$, a hyperplane is an $(n−1)$-dimensional  affine subspace not just $(n−1)$-dimensional subspace. I think that your answer should be improved.